# JSON Encoding a map in Elixir using Poison

Tags: json, elixir

I'm trying to parse my map into a json string, how would i do that using poison?

I've tried the following.

```
iex(19)> test = %{"api_key" => "sklfjklasfj"}
%{"api_key" => "sklfjklasfj"}
iex(20)> Poison.Encoder.encode(test, [])
[123, [[34, ["api_key"], 34], 58, [34, ["sklfjklasfj"], 34]], 125]
```

What i would expect was

```
"{"api_key": "sklfjklasfj"}"
```

Comment: Note you can also use `Poison.encode/1` and `Poison.decode/1` without touching `Poison.Encoder`.

Comment: Thank you whatyouhide :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I realised poison was returning a char_list, which can be casted to a string like so.

```
iex(27)> to_string Poison.Encoder.encode(test, [])
"{\"api_key\":\"sklfjklasfj\"}"
```

As of October 2017 (Poison v3), the code would be

```
iex(27)> to_string Poison.encode_to_iodata!(test, [])
"{\"api_key\":\"sklfjklasfj\"}"
```

or simply

```
iex(27)> Poison.encode!(test, [])
"{\"api_key\":\"sklfjklasfj\"}"
```

without the `to_string` call.

Comment: It's not a `char_list`, which is just a flat list of code points; it's an IO list, which can be arbitrarily nested. You can send them directly as file or socket IO, and they'll get flattened when needed. See http://dev.af83.com/2012/01/16/erlang-iolist.html, for example.

Comment: Note now in the newest version of Poison you'd use `encode_to_iodata!` instead of just `encode`.

Comment: Or just use `encode!` and drop the `to_string` call.